# Tratar arquivo como String em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arquivo, fs, newline

Estou tendo o seguinte problema : desejo realizar a contagem de quebras de linhas, ou seja, a quantide de **'\n'** em um arquivo. Para isso, desejo ao ler o arquivo tratá-lo como uma String. Estou tentando da seguinte maneira :

```
    const fs = require('fs') 

    const contents = fs.readFileSync('<caminho para o arquivo>', 'uft-8')//permitir ler o arquivo desejado

    const matches = contents.match(/\n/g)//identifica o '\n' no arquivo

    const count = matches.length//indica a qtd de '\n' no arquivo

    console.log(count)
```

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro :

```
**internal/fs/utils.js:85
    throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING(encoding);
    ^
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "uft-8" is invalid for option "encoding"
    at assertEncoding (internal/fs/utils.js:85:11)
    at getOptions (internal/fs/utils.js:221:5)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:357:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gabriel_rc/Área de Trabalho/Curso de NodeJS/exercícios/3.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING'
}**
```

Como resolver isto?

Comment: O correto é `utf8`, e não `utf-8`. Leia a mensagem de erro...

Comment: fazendo 'uft8' ainda assim retorna erro. TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "uft8" is invalid for option "encoding"

Comment: Se mudar o segundo argumento para `{ encoding: 'utf8' }` resolve o problema?

Comment: O mais engraçado é que era para funcionar até mesmo com `utf-8` (o que a mensagem de erro acusa de estar errado). [Veja aqui.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlgpR.png) Testei também com `utf8`, e também funcionou... Qual a versão do seu Node?

Comment: A minha versão é a 'v12.16.1'

Comment: Obg @Luiz Felipe pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como o @Luiz Felipe citou nos comentários, você colocou o encoding errado, porém você fez isso duas vezes.

A primeira vez como `'uft-8'` conforme seu exemplo:

> ```
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "uft-8" is invalid for option "encoding"
> ```

E a segunda, como `'uft8'` conforme o erro que você colocou nos comentários:

> ```
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING]: The value "uft8" is invalid for option "encoding"
> ```

Ambas as vezes você inverteu a sigla, o prefixo é **`utf`** e as duas vezes você escreveu `uft`.

Portanto, a principal correção no seu código é:

```
const contents = fs.readFileSync('myfile.txt', 'utf8');//permitir ler o arquivo desejado
```

Seu código então ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const contents = fs.readFileSync('myfile.txt', 'utf8');//permitir ler o arquivo desejado

const matches = contents.match(/\n/g);//identifica o '\n' no arquivo

const count = matches.length;//indica a qtd de '\n' no arquivo

console.log(count);
```

Vale a pena citar existe a possibilidade de exceção caso o arquivo não existe e caso o mesmo não possua uma quebra de linha, atualmente o código trabalha na certeza da existência do arquivo e na certeza que existe ao menos uma quebra de linha com `\n`.

> Veja este exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/UnitedEsteemedRuntimeenvironment
>
> Documentação: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Já estou tão vidrado no `utf` que nem tinha percebido que tinha sido colocado `uft`. Que olho! :D

Comment: Pois é... Também foi difícil entender porque não tinha funcionado! :D

Comment: Obg @DanielMendes, Funcionou.